# List bitshift operations not commutative?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, bit-manipulation

I'm running python-3.2.3 on raspbian, and I've encountered some unusual results from my code which I debugged a bit in the python shell:

```
    >>> a = [ 7, 33]
    >>> a = [7,33]
    >>> a[0]<<8
    1792
    >>> a[1]
    33
    >>> a[0]<<8 + a[1]
    15393162788864
    >>> a[1] + a[0]<<8
    10240
    >>> a[0]*2**8 + a[1]
    1825
```

What is going on here that I'm missing?  I can work around this issue, but something is going on behind the scene that I'm not understanding.  I would expect all of these operations to have the same result.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `a` again after each operation? It's not clear why you think the list is impacting anything.

Comment: Mind the operator precedence.

Comment: Hint: Writing an operator closer to an operand doesn't magically give it precendence.  :-)  Another hint: 7 << 41 is greater than 40 << 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bit shift operators have lower [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than any of the other operations you're doing, so your expressions are equivalent to:

```
>>> a[0] << (8 + a[1])
15393162788864
>>> (a[1] + a[0]) << 8
10240
```